# GWT - How to add an easy ComboBox

Tags: gwt, combobox

I need the GWT Class that describes an easy ComboBox. Looks strange, but i can't use it. I found [this](http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/form/ComboBox.html) but if i try `ComboBox combo=new ComboBox();` i can't import the package (there is no way to import it on NetBeans). The same for `ComboBoxItem cbItem = new ComboBoxItem();` (but this should be for Smart GWT Library).

These are the actual import :

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ClickListener;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.InlineLabel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
```

Maybe some conflicts? I ask sorry, i think this is a stupid question :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The link you point if from the GXT framework, so you need to import the proper library.

What you're looking for is probably the `ListBox` widget: see the examples [here](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwListBox)